# Can I install any file browser if I don't already have one

Tags: installation, recovery-mode, apk

Ok. Long story short I'm an idiot. I have a rooted Kyocera Hydro, with no recovery(no access to cpu to port my own). I deleted stock file and internet browsers. I also have no access to the play store because im only on wifi and the signal bars are grey. In an attempt to fix that I did a factory reset. So, since no signal, cannot sign in to google account, no file or internet browser. I have all my apps backed up on the sd cards, and other phones to bluetooth files. By changing .apk to .jpg I can send es file over, but cannot change back to install. am I missing something. Is there any way to install es remotely with out a cpu. Oh and I can't flash stock rom cause no recovery mode. Help?

Comment: See also: [How can I install an app given only its APK file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5566/16575) / [Install APK from external_sd](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/8354/16575) / [How do I install a .apk on my Nexus 7 using the browser?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47518/16575)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot install `apk` without a computer or working Wi-Fi or data connection.

But, you can install `apk` via `adb` to your device.

> **Disclaimer: You need a computer/laptop in order to accomplish this.**

Since the device is operational, you can enable `USB debugging`. Then follow the steps given in this [thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64799/installing-app-without-copying-apk-file/64864).
An excerpt from the thread is given below.

> You can manually install your app by doing the following:
>
> 1. Install Android SDK tools from [this page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (Download for other platforms → SDK Tools Only.)
> 2. Install USB drivers for the phone (usually from manufacturer's site.)
> 3. Turn on USB debugging on the phone (in **Settings** → **Developer options**)
> 4. Connect the phone via USB (you can also do this over Wi-Fi with a number of apps if the phone is rooted.)
> 5. Open Command Prompt or Terminal and navigate to the "platform-tools" sub-directory of where you installed the SDK tools.
> 6. Issue the following command: `adb install path_to_apk\your_app.apk`
>
> Keep in mind though that you are still essentially "letting them have"
>   the apk, since the installation simply copies the APK file to the
>   appropriate directory on the phone (usually `/data/app` or
>   `/data/app-private`) and registers it with Android's Package Manager. 
>   A knowledgeable enough user can still retrieve the APK.

Thanks to [Chahk](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/3646/chahk) for his answer. Thank him for the solution.

> **Correction:** In step 1, in place of SDK tools, you can just copy just the platform binaries (`adb` and `fastboot`) and continue to step 2.

Comment: And if you don't want to install the entire SDK (not really needed if you don't plan to develop for Android), see: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)

Comment: @Izzy, you are right. In fact, you can just download the platform binaries and can work with them.

Comment: In fact, I even used the most basic solution (just copied the two binaries :) And besides: *You cannot install apk without a computer or working Wi-Fi or data connection.* is not 100% true. You can copy the `.apk` to SDCard, and try to open it using the web browser – amongst others (see the other questions linked above ;) +1, though :)

Comment: @Izzy, never knew it could be done via browser. Thanks for the tip. Also, OP doesn't seem to have a browser as he mentioned he has deleted them. Will edit the answer for the binaries.

Comment: There are plenty of alternatives (though most not working for OP as he deleted the "core apps" and lacks connection), e.g. also sending the `.apk` by mail and running if from the attachments.